# How to obtain "found xx results in the category X "?

Tags: views

I 've got many exposed filters into a view : all I want to do is to show the total number of item per **categories** that I obtain from a research.
I mean something like this: I have items organized into categories and sub-categories. When I apply a filter, I want this description at the begin of the result list:

i.e.

*We have found **n°45** items into category **"X"**, subcategory **"Y"***

where "X" is the main category and "Y" the subcategory , selected in the filter for the research.

I know in Views3 I can show the number of the results by setting "Global:result summary" in the head, but since I want to show the category and the subcategory where the items where found, I think it should be better to insert all this instructions by a code ...

I found following code in order to show the number of results for research of 1 or more records :

```
<?php
  $view = views_get_current_view();
$count = ( $view->total_rows );
if (count($view->exposed_input)) 
print "$count results per categories";
?>
```

How can I modify this code in order to show also the **category and subcategory** from which the results belong ?

Thank you for your help!

Ciao

Comment: Did you tried with `NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR` which is default in views ?

Comment: So you're saying that the category and subcategory are filters for this view?  That means that the total number of results *will* be the total found for the subcategory but the number for the category should be larger than the returned set?  Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Hi  Nikhil M, sorry but I don't understand what you want to tell me.

Comment: Hi @Boriana, the counter is ok: I've 1 taxonomy filter (term_node_tid_depth) and when apply it the code above it show me exactly numbers of items of search. I want however that the result show me also for which category belong: ex "We have found n°45 items into category **"Cars"**, subcategory **"Cabrio"** . Thanks

Comment: Not found any solution yet: have you got any idea ?